# Integrate Google Analytics Measurement Id with React JS

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics

I am creating a new web project in Google Analytics.

1. Why am i getting a Measurement iD instead of Tracking ID?
2. How can i connect Measurement ID with React JS?
3. Can i give localhost URL in website URL?

I have added below code in my App.js but it is not getting integrated with Google Analytics

```
useEffect(() => {
  ReactGA.initialize('G-*******SYL');
  ReactGA.pageview('/');
}, [])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you create a **Universal Analytics** Property (as shown in following image) and use the relative identifier UA-XXXXXXX-X because Google Analytics 4 Property ID (G-XXXXXXXX) currently has the measurement protocol in alpha version, also React does not support it yet:

[image]

Comment: It gives you the option to create both a G and UA property at the same time.

Comment: It is deprecated soon!

Comment: Yes, in July 2023.

Answer (score -2):

Create a new property, with selected "Create a Universal Analytics property".
It'll show you tracking id.